# MCvFont library is missing at Emgu 3.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, image-processing, emgucv

I integrated my project on Visual Studio 2010 with Emgu 3.0 and I'm working on detection object project , but when I'm using MCvFont like the following line I get error because the library is missing , This library is removed from the last version of Emgu or what ?

```
 MCvFont f2 = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: Have you added a reference in your visual studio project, to that library?  And do you have a "using ..." statement at the top of your code, including the relevant library?

Comment: I added all references that is found in installed Emgu folder on my computer then yes I called all required libraries but this library is missing I couldn't find it when I'm calling it through code

Comment: Note: I'm using Windows virtual machine on mac .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX`   can be `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FontFace.HersheyTriplex`   in Emgu 3.0.

`MCvFont`   present in   `Emgu.CV.Structure`   at Emgu_2.4.10,
but it missing at Emgu_3.0.0. I checked this in emgu version history.

You can heal this code by add to reference Emgu.CV from Emgu_2.4.10,
catch this dll https://dropmefiles.com/AZvmM

Instruction to convert 2.4.x code to 3.0 can be found http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial#Upgrading_from_Emgu_CV_2.x_to_3.x

Do you making face or eyes recognition?
This is my first answer at stackoverflow :)

Comment: Really I used the Emgu 2.4 at the end to solve this error and another error that is appeared in version 3.0.
About your question no I don't make face or eyes rec. only I'm working on detect objects in images .
Thank you for your first answer in the stack-overflow world :)

Answer (score 1):

I did not want to add an extra dll to have backwards compability with 2.x versions of Emgu for code written in a 3.x version of Emgu. As @Константин Марков points out in his answer, MCvFont is no longer a part of the library in 3.x versions of Emgu.

I am assuming that your final goal is to write some text in an image. So, I you do not mind changing your code, you would need to rewrite it in order to use the method CvInvoke.PutText to accomplish that goal.

According to the official documentation [page](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/37ada42e-a5c3-caa1-dfa7-a4a64251a059.htm) for the aforementioned method, CvInvoke.PutText

> Renders the text in the image with the specified font and color. The
>   printed text is clipped by ROI rectangle. Symbols that do not belong
>   to the specified font are replaced with the rectangle symbol.

This is the method signature in C#

```
public static void PutText(
    IInputOutputArray img,
    string text,
    Point org,
    FontFace fontFace,
    double fontScale,
    MCvScalar color,
    int thickness = 1,
    LineType lineType = LineType.EightConnected,
    bool bottomLeftOrigin = false
)
```

Below is a description for each parameter in the method

- img

  - Type: `Emgu.CV.IInputOutputArray`
  - Description: Input image
- text

  - Type: `System.String`
  - Description: String to print
- org

  - Type: `System.Drawing.Point`
  - Description: Coordinates of the bottom-left corner of the first letter
- fontFace

  - Type: `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FontFace`
  - Description: Font type.
- fontScale

  - Type: `System.Double`
  - Description: Font scale factor that is multiplied by the font-specific base size.
- color

  - Type: `Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar`
  - Description: Text color
- thickness (Optional)

  - Type: `System.Int32`
  - Description: Thickness of the lines used to draw a text.
- lineType (Optional)

  - Type: `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType`
  - Description: Line type
- bottomLeftOrigin (Optional)

  - Type: `System.Boolean`
  - Description: When true, the image data origin is at the bottom-left corner. Otherwise, it is at the top-left corner.

This is code example taken straight from this [source](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Hello_World_in_CSharp)

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using System.Drawing;

...

//Create a 3 channel image of 400x200
using (Mat img = new Mat(200, 400, DepthType.Cv8U, 3)) 
{
   img.SetTo(new Bgr(255, 0, 0).MCvScalar); // set it to Blue color

   //Draw "Hello, world." on the image using the specific font
   CvInvoke.PutText(
      img, 
      "Hello, world", 
      new System.Drawing.Point(10, 80), 
      FontFace.HersheyComplex, 
      1.0, 
      new Bgr(0, 255, 0).MCvScalar);

   //Show the image using ImageViewer from Emgu.CV.UI
   ImageViewer.Show(img, "Test Window");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
CvInvoke.PutText(img,
"Hello, world", 
new System.Drawing.Point(10, 80), 
FontFace.HersheyComplex, 1.0, 
new Bgr(0, 255, 0).MCvScalar);
```

reference:
 http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Hello_World_in_CSharp#Emgu_CV_3.0_2

Comment: You have to give a simple expanation